# Conditional Attribute Statement in View.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I am attempting to do something seemingly simple, but experiencing odd results (and not my area of expertise).  On the `view.phtml` page, I need to print a **small message**, based on two **custom attribute values** (brand & classification).

- If the product = BrandA and it's a computer, then echo "message 1"
- If the product = BrandA and it's not a computer, then echo "message 2".

But for some reason, this is not working as expected.  if BrandA is in a different category, like hard drives, it still sets message 1, then it might work as expected, and revert back again.

I think this might be due to this "$product = Mage::registry('current_product');" but so gracious if anyone can provide any insight!

Side note, if I echo $productAttribute or $productClass, this seems to work as expected.

Again, thank you to anyone who can push me in the right direction.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$productAttribute = $product->getAttributeText('brand');
$productClass = $product->getData('classification');

if(($productAttribute == "BrandA" || $productAttribute == "BrandB" || $productAttribute == "BrandC") && ($productClass == "Computers")): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('1')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if(($productAttribute == "BrandA") && ($productClass != "Computers")): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('2')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```